# Cant move a simple button around a constraint layout

Tags: java, android, android-studio, mobile

I have a constraint layout defined, and inside it a button. The problem is I cant seem to move the button around as it is fixed on the top left of the screen.

Any help?

[image: the button edges cant be dragged, it just sits there idle.]

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="16dp"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button" />
```

Comment: Do you want to move it programmatically? Or frombthe design view?

Comment: From the design view, it just wont work from the design view and its frustrating.

Comment: You haven't connected the constraint yet.. connect the constraint and drag the horizontal biaz to place the button.

Comment: try adding constraint for the button

Comment: all of that functionality isn't working.

Comment: Can you show error with gif it seems there is an error in your IDE?

Answer (score 2):

That helped for me.
Android studio -> Build -> Clean Project.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: Man this works! I had the same problem and I spent an hour on trying to figure out if I'd overlooked anything...and it turned out to be just simple bug.

Answer (score 1):

Please use constraints, in design tab, or Text tab, to position the widget, in addition to adding margin. 
XML code:
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"

You could add margin in Design tab (properties pane on right-top) and then see the added XML in Text tab to view the change in XML.

By default, in Constraint layout, any widget falls to the right-top if it is not constrained.

Answer (score 0):

for movement in the constraint layout, you must define your widgets like below code:
this code can move your widget to the right of the screen:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/img"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    />
```